# Shell one-liner to add a line to a sorted file

Tags: shell, sorting, sed, pipe

I want to add a line to a text file so that the result is sorted, where the text file was originally sorted.  For example:

```
cp file tmp; echo "new line" >> tmp; sort tmp > file; rm -f tmp
```

I'd REALLY like to do it w/o the temp file and w/o the semicolons (using pipes instead?); using `sed` would be acceptable.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo "New Line" | sort -o file - file
```

The `-o file` means write result to file (and it is explicitly safe to have any of the input files as the output file).  The `-` on its own means 'read standard input' which contains the new line of information.  The `file` at the end means 'also read `file`'.  This would work with any Unix sort from (at least) 7th Edition UNIX™ circa 1978 onwards, and possibly even before that.  There are no temporary files or dependencies on other utilities.

Given that a single line is 'sorted' and the file is also in sorted order, you can probably speed the process up by just merging the two sorted inputs:

```
echo "New Line" | sort -o file -m - file
```

That also would have worked with even really old sort commands.

Comment: If somebody was looking for this, sort also has a lesser known -u flag, to only keep unique rows, which has the same behavior as using sort | uniq, but doesn't need a temporary file.

Answer (score 7):

This is the shortest one liner I can think of without any temporary files:

```
$ echo "something" >> file; sort file -o file
```

Comment: and this DOES use a temporary file. its just that sort is creating it for you.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily use a temporary file; `sort` may be able to keep all the data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you'll either need to resort or `comm` them together (if they're already presorted) *assuming* they have no tabs, which will save you the sort (which can produce temp files and overhead depending on file size).

Alternative:
`comm -3 file <(echo "new line") |tr -d '\t'`

This might be the "shortest":
`sort -m file <(echo "new line")`

Comment: The `sort -m` option is good, with the caveat that process substitution (`<(echo new line)`) like that is `bash` specific (and not really necessary).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - You're right, process sub can be easily done with a pipe, but that was already presented. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Large files / performance**:

Convert your file to an SQLite database with a single indexed column and query that.

Or re-implement a file-based B-tree or hash map yourself, which how SQLite implements indexes...

I think it is impossible to insert into sorted text files efficiently: even if you do a binary search, you still have to copy everything that comes after the insertion point, and that disk operation will be the bottleneck: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87772/add-lines-to-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-huge-file

For search, `sgrep` might work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/423886/efficiently-search-sorted-file/701237#701237

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without any semicolons and without a temp file, but probably not without depending on some utilities that might not be everywhere (like awk with in-place file modification, or perl).

Why don't you want to use temp files or semicolons?

Edit: since semicolons are ok, how about:

```
val=$(cat file); { echo "$val"; echo "new line"; } | sort > file
```

Comment: I'm more concerned about temp files (get messy if something fails) than semicolons (this will be called within another program, and would make diagnosing any problems more difficult).

Comment: Sort may *implicitly* create temp files

Comment: @Xepoch not on the filesystem. It would be silly not to be ok with unlinked temp files.

Comment: @thepaul, check out the `-T` option on sort.  Answer above avoids that I'm pretty sure.  It is silly in most cases, but I've done AB analysis on huge files that did too much tmp IO on `sort`.

Comment: Yeah, unlinked temp files still need to be created at a point in the filesystem where the user has write access. Doesn't mean it leaves a file lying around. Any actual disk i/o resulting from the sort operation here would be due to page swapping.